# how to convert this spark snippet into a sql queries

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to convert this spark snippet into a sql queries I dont have much knowledge in spark so this is the reason I am not able to convert this snippet into the sql. If any one have an idea please let me know to vconvert this snippet

```
flagged_claims_sdf=flagged_claims_sdf.withColumn('greatest_assoc_anom_score', 
                                                    F.greatest('anom_mod_usage_lift_proc_score',
                                                                 
                                                                 'anom_mod_usage_lift_prov_score',
                                                                 
                                                                 'anom_mod_usage_lift_proc_prov_score',
                                                                 
                                                                 'anom_mod_usage_lift_provstate_score',
                                                                 'anom_mod_usage_lift_proc_xproc_score'))\
                                        .withColumn('anomaly_summary',
```

Comment: almost all spark functions have an SQL function of the same name depending on your dbms. please tag and mention your dbms for better reach.

Answer (score 1):

According to [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.greatest.html), what your snippet of code is doing is creating a new column called `greatest_assoc_anom_score` that contains the maximum of 5 columns following columns from each row:
`'anom_mod_usage_lift_proc_score', 'anom_mod_usage_lift_prov_score', 'anom_mod_usage_lift_proc_prov_score', 'anom_mod_usage_lift_provstate_score', 'anom_mod_usage_lift_proc_xproc_score'`.

In SQL, you can do that in several ways, as explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4067/find-max-value-from-multiple-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/).